# How do I check if a file pointer is valid?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using fseek and fread on a FILE * like this:

```
void CAudioDataItem::finalizeItem_ReadEncodedBytesWithoutDecoding(FILE* uFile, CLog* uLog, double& uTimeReadEncodedBytes)
{
    //t.start();
    fseek(uFile, iFirstByteToRead, SEEK_SET);
    fread(&m_EncodedBytes[0], sizeof(unsigned char), m_lLenEncodedBytes, uFile);
    //t.stop();
```

However, it doesn't work, the bytes are all 0.

I suspect that somewhere in my app, the FILE pointer gets invalid or something else becomes wrong with this pointer.

How could I check if this file handle is still valid and "usable"?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

---

Here is a screenshot of a situation where it still works.
As one can see, the `_Placeholder` is different. What does this `_Placeholder` mean?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question is on C++ as *one* of the tags imply,

> **There's typically no way to tell if the pointer dangles**, i.e., points to memory that no longer holds the object the pointer is supposed to point to.

from [Effective Modern C++](https://www.aristeia.com/EMC++.html), in the introduction to *Chapter 4 - Smart Pointers*, page 117.

If it's on C, then from the comments we know the same point holds for C.

As regards `_Placeholder=0x00000000` when it doesn't work vs `_Placeholder=0x1bc715bf` when it works, I'm not sure why the numbers (which are memory addresses, I believe) are those that you see; maybe `_Placeholder=0x00000000` means that something in the program has set the pointer to `nullptr`, but the point is that once that (or something else which invalidates the pointer) has happened, you can't do anything to query it.

The only way to go about this is to surrender to the evidence that the program has a bug that results in [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66816831/5825294) and try to debug it.

Comment: Same thing applies to C.

Comment: @Enlico I have added yet another screenshot where it still works.
As one can see, the "placeholder" is different. What does this placeholder mean?

Comment: @tmighty it means there isn't a meaningful name for the (first? only?) data member of `FILE` objects

Comment: @tmighty what `placeholder` means isn't important. It's is an internal implementation detail. It's probably an [opaque pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer), but it could be just about anything else. You're much better served by tracking down and killing whatever bug is causing you grief. Perhaps you can put an  On Memory Change breakpoint on it's location and see if it helps you find when/where it got changed.